# error "array to string conversion" in FacebookCurl.php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have this error.... "array to string conversion" in line 66 in FacebookCurl.php, I'm trying to update this: custom_image from page/tabs/app_id...

I get the value the custom_image from input type file and use the multipart/form-data....

This is my code in php...

```
session_start();
require '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
require '/../config/configfb.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

//app_id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($config['appId'], $config['secret']);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('xxxxxxxxxx');

try {  
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  if($session):
    $_SESSION['facebook']=$session->getToken();
    header('Location: xxxx');
  endif;

  if (isset($_SESSION['facebook'])):
    $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebook']);

      if (isset($_POST['custom_name']))
      {
        //get value of input type text custom_name
        $custom_name=$_POST['custom_name'];
        //get value of input type file custom_image
        $custom_image=$_FILES['custom_image'];

        //get the access token
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts');
        $response = $request->execute();
        $getAcounts = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

        foreach ($getAcounts['data'] as $keyAcc) {
           $keyAcc ->id; 
          if($keyAcc->id == $page){
            $_SESSION['access_token']=$keyAcc->access_token;
          } 
        }

        $access_token=$_SESSION['access_token'];

        $session = new FacebookSession($access_token);

        //Update custom_name and custom_image
        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/'.$tab,
          array (
              'custom_name' => $custom_name
              'custom_image' => $custom_image
            )
        );
        $response = $request->execute();
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

        $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/'.$tab);
          $response = $request->execute();
          $getInf = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
          $_SESSION['getInf'] = $getInf;        

      }
  endif; 
} 
catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} 
catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

if ($session) {
  // Logged in
}
```

The error "array to string conversion" in line 66 in FacebookCurl.php say this...

```
<?php
/**
   * Set an array of options to a curl resource
   *
   * @param array $options
   */
  public function setopt_array(array $options)
  {
    curl_setopt_array($this->curl, $options);
  }
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: When exactly does the error occur? What is that array which you are passing? Can you echo it somewhere?

Comment: var_dump($custom_image);

array (size=5)
 'name' =>
   array (size=1)
  0 => string 'ico.jpg' (Lenght=7)
 'type' =>
   array (size=1)
  0 => string 'image/jpeg' (Length=10)
 'tmp_name' =>
   array (size=1)
  0 => string 'C:\wamp\tmp\phpDB3.tmp' (Lenght=22)
 'error' =>
   array (size=1)
  0 => int 0
 'size' =>
   array (size=1)
  0 => int 11556

Comment: the error is when i try do the request...
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'POST', '/'.$tab,
          array (
              'custom_name' => $custom_name,
              'custom_image' => $custom_image //here
            )
);

says.. Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\WebquitectoTabs\vendor\facebook\php-sdk-v4\src\Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl.php on line 66
I think is the curl but i don't know nothing about this....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the `$custom_image` just the `path` to the image is required but you are assigning the whole `$_FILES[]` compound array to it.
Try replacing this line `$custom_image=$_FILES['custom_image'];` in your code with this, `$custom_image=$_FILES['custom_image']['tmp_name'];` and see if it works